# What does "threading in ASP.NET and WCF" mean?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I really like this article "[Request threading in ASP.NET and WCF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmetzgar/archive/2011/06/14/request-threading-in-asp-net-and-wcf.aspx)," except for the fact that his reference to ASP.NET is vague.

I read the article, and at first I thought he was implying an ASP.NET client invoking a WCF service.  But as I re-read the article more carefully, I think he was saying that...

WCF, when hosted in IIS, must necessarily have ASP.NET as part of the early pipeline.  Thus, if you are using WCF hosted in IIS, you are therefore dealing with "ASP.NET and WCF."

Could someone confirm or deny this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why must it be vague? The call stacks shown in the article clearly reveal that under the hood ASP.NET and WCF are twisted on .NET Framework 3.* (WCF reuses some of the ASP.NET elements to handle incoming requests).

This is expected and not surprising, as that's the early implementation of WCF. As the same article explains, on .NET 4 WCF and ASP.NET are more isolated from each other.

You don't need anyone to confirm or deny that, as if you like, you can decompile every bits of .NET Framework and do your own research.

Comment: Perhaps if I had not read the article on my cell phone, I would have made better sense of call-stack snapshots. :)